# Data constructor not in scope

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm learning Haskell and writing a simple program. Now I'm getting a problem, which for me, is quite confusing. Here is the code:

```
data VariableName = X|Y deriving Show  
getValue :: VariableName -> Int
getValue X = 5
getValue Y = 13

data Expression = Constant|Variable|Add|Multiply deriving Show
evaluate :: Expression -> Int
evaluate Constant x = x
evaluate Variable x = getValue x
evaluate Add x y = x+y
evaluate Multiply x y = x * y
```

I expect the output:

```
Constant  20  = 20
```

but I'm getting

```
*Main> evaluate Constant 20

<interactive>:79:1: error:
    Variable not in scope: evaluate :: t0 -> Integer -> t

<interactive>:79:10: error: Data constructor not in scope: Constant
```

But when e.g.:  I write

```
*Main> getValue X
5
```

Which is the right answer. I just started Haskell, which is way this is quite confusing for me. Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to add parenthesis, right now it looks like you define `evaluate Constant x` with two variables.

Comment: Furthermore an `Expression` like `Constant | Variable | Add | Multiply` does not seem to make much sense in the first place, I would expect `Constant Int | Variable VariableName | Add Expression Expression | Multiply Expression Expression` for example, since then these are *parameters* of the expression.

Comment: My guess is that you are inputting this code line by line through ghci, since the code `evaluate :: Expression -> Int; evaluate Constant x = x` should not even compile, along with the comments by Willem.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried adding every possible combination of parantheses, and it still gives me the same error. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at the errors:

> ```
> Variable not in scope: evaluate :: t0 -> Integer -> t
>
> Data constructor not in scope: Constant
> ```

These mean that you haven't defined the `evaluate` function and the `Constant` constructor (even though you clearly have). But you say when you use `getValue` and `X`, those work?

This doesn't appear to be the (extremely common) multiline `ghci` confusion, as suggested in a comment. First, the error you get from that tends to be a `non-exhaustive patterns`, which is not what you're getting. Second, your `ghci` prompt reads `*Main>` instead of `Prelude>`, which implies that you've `:load`ed a file. Said file simply hasn't defined the code you expect it to have.

My guess is that is you wrote the first part of the code in the file, then `:load`ed it properly, then modified the file and forgot to `:reload`, so the changes you made were never loaded.

Another possibility is that you put a `module Main (VariableName (..), getValue) where` at the beginning of your file, and forgot to add your new exports to it. But that seems less likely.

If none of the above works, just try closing `ghci`, opening it again, and `:load`ing the file anew.

---

Even once you fix that issue, there are a number of other errors you'll run into, mostly to do with parentheses. In Haskell, When you write something like this:

```
evaluate Constant 20
```

It means "call the `evaluate` function, and pass it two arguments: `Constant` and `20`". This implies `evaluate :: Expression -> Int -> Int`, but you really want `evaluate :: Expression -> Int`. So you need parentheses:

```
evaluate (Constant 20)
```

This means "call the `Constant` constructor with one argument `20`, and pass that value as the single argument to `evaluate`".

---

Not only must you make this change at the call site, you also need it in the definition. Currently, you have:

```
evaluate :: Expression -> Int
evaluate Constant x = x
evaluate Variable x = getValue x
evaluate Add x y = x+y
evaluate Multiply x y = x * y
```

Each of these patterns expects a different number of arguments: the first two expect two arguments, and the last two expect three arguments. The problem is that `x` and `y` are being seen as arguments to the function, not the constructors. To change this, you need parentheses:

```
evaluate :: Expression -> Int
evaluate (Constant x) = x
evaluate (Variable x) = getValue x
evaluate (Add x y) = x+y
evaluate (Multiply x y) = x * y
```

---

The final change you need to make is in the constructor definition: you need to tell the constructors that they take arguments in the first place. Currently your data definition looks like this (I've added formatting):

```
data Expression = Constant
                | Variable
                | Add
                | Multiply
                deriving Show
```

None of these constructors currently take arguments: they're values (like `True`, `X`, `Nothing`, etc), rather than value constructors. This is not what you want. You need to give the types of the arguments for each constructor, like so:

```
data Expression = Constant Int
                | Variable VariableName
                | Add      Int Int
                | Multiply Int Int
                deriving Show
```